# How can I limit the results in a Sharepoint survey?

Tags: 2013, lookup-column, survey

I did create a default SP 2013 survey with the survey app.
Possible answers per question: "Y" or "N".
After each answer I want to evaluate per question how many "Y" were answered in total. How can I achieve this - if possible with formula only?

Comment: Do you mean during the survey or after the survey is done?

Comment: during the survey

Comment: Idea is to use the survey for an event registration. Each event has limited seats available. After an event is full, further "Y"es answer shall be not possible any longer.

Answer (score 0):

The OOTB Survey is still the 13 year old SP2003 technology,
nothing much you can do with it other than ductaping code onto it.

Use a Custom list and create your own survey,
you still need some (CSR/JSLink) javascript coding to get the functionality you are after